# Regex to validate credit card number only for three specific formats in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write regex to custom validate mastercard and visa cards. If the string is anything except the three formats mentioned below the `re.match` should return `None`.

This is what I have so far mastercard

```
regex = "^5[1-5][-0-9 ]+"
print re.match(regex, "5455-1107-!64220469")
```

returns an object. Should return `None`.

For visa I have the regex as

```
regex = "^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?"
```

Only accepted formats are

```
1234123412341234
1234-1234-1234-1234
1234 1234 1234 1234
```

A format in any other form should return `None`.

How can I improve my regex or should I approach this some other way?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just remove `-` and space, then validate that the result is all digits and the correct length with `^\\d{16}$` ?

Comment: yes that would be easier.thanks

Comment: @JavaNut13 would you recommend using ```replace``` ? because then I run into issues like escaping conditions with ```---``` or ```    ````  and that is part of the valid format.

Comment: I would do this: `"124 1234- 1234--1234".replace("-", "").replace(" ", "")`

Comment: @JavaNut13 right , but if the string has ```--``` then its not a valid format. ```replace("-", "")``` removes all occurrences of ```-```.

Answer (score 0):

It is not trivial to solve this validation with a regex if you are worried about things like double dashes, at least if you want to ensure that you have either one or four blocks at the same time. Here is a little more resistant approach:

```
import re


def check_valid_credit_card_format(card):
    parts = re.split(' |-', card)

    if len(parts) == 1:
        if len(parts[0]) != 16:
            # print 'Credit card does not consist of 16 digits.'
            return False
    elif len(parts) == 4:
        if not all(len(part) == 4 for part in parts):
            # print 'Credit card does not consist of 4 blocks of 4 digits each.'
            return False
    else:
        # print 'Credit card consists of an invalid number of blocks.'
        return False

    if not all(part.isdigit() for part in parts):
        # print 'Credit card does not only contain digits.'
        return False

    return True


def get_vendor_for_credit_card(card):
    if card.startswith('4'):
        return 'Visa'

    if re.match('^5[1-5]', card):
        return 'MasterCard'

    return None


if check_valid_credit_card_format(credit_card):
    print get_vendor_for_credit_card(credit_card)
else:
    print 'Invalid format.'
```

First, we check whether the format of the credit card is valid. A valid format is either one block of 16 digits or four blocks of four digits each.
If it is, we check which vendor the card belongs to. In the case of Visa you do not even need a regex.

**Notes:**
This test does not fail if the credit card is separated in 4 blocks by both dashes and spaces, e.g. `1234 1234-1234 1234`. This may or may not be what you want.
Also, this is *probably* not the fastest way to do this, so depending on your application you might want to optimize it. This snippet here is just to make it easier to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : regex = "[\d]+((-|\s)?[\d]+)+"

**Test this regex online**
 - [Pythex.org](http://pythex.org/)

> it will accept formats like
>
> 1234123412341234,  1234-1234-1234-1234,  1234 1234 1234 1234

Comment: However, this allows credit card numbers of arbitrary lengths.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
\d{4}[\s\-]*\d{4}[\s\-]*\d{4}[\s\-]*\d{4}
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither of your regex checks against invalid characters *after* the match.  You need to anchor the end of the match to reject stuff after the accepted expression.

So, for example, `re.match("^5[1-5][-0-9 ]+", "51 foo")` matches, and really anything after the third character could be complete garbage.  A trivial fix would be `"^5[1-5][-0-9 ]+$"` (notice the dollar anchor at the end) which however still doesn't do anything to check the length of the input.

Your examples all show sixteen digits, so you could simply do

```
regex=r'[45]\d{3}(?:[- ]?\d{4}){3}$'
```

to allow optional dashes or spaces between the digit groups.  That's a four or a five, followed by three digits, followed by three groups of four digits, with optional leading space or dash.

If the inputs come from an on-line form, for example, you should probably be more lenient about repeated spaces or dashes, and perhaps simply preprocess the input to remove any non-digits, then check for a length of sixteen and verify that the first digit is one that you accept.